# Newton-raphson script freezes in attempt to root great numbers

Tags: python, square-root

I am trying to do square root using newton-raphson algorithm of random numbers given by this formula:
a = m * 10 ^c 
where m is random float in range (0,1) and c is random integer in range (-300,300). 
Code i wrote works perfectly with precision of root as 0.01 and c in range (-30,30) but freezes or returns wrong results when i use c range given in task.

here is code for newton function
def newton_raphson(a):
    iterations_count = 0

```
x_n_result = a/2

while abs(x_n_result - a / x_n_result) > 0.01:

    x_n_result = (x_n_result + a/x_n_result)/2
    iterations_count = iterations_count + 1

    if x_n_result*x_n_result == a:

        break

iterations.append(iterations_count)
results.append(x_n_result)
print("Result of function", x_n_result)

return
```

and part where numbers to root are randomized

```
for i in range(0, 100):
    m = random.uniform(0, 1)
    c = random.randint(-30, 30)
    a = m * 10 **c
    random_c.append(c)
    numbers.append(a)

    print("Number to root : ", i, "|",  a, '\n')
    newton_raphson(a)
```

plot of the amount of iteration from the value of c

```
plt.bar(random_c, iterations, color='red')
```

Script is supposed to root 100 random numbers and then plot amount of iteration required to root number from values of c. Problem is like i said before with proper range of c value. I believe it has to do something with range of variables. Any sugestion how to solve this?

Comment: Floating point numbers have limited precision.  If the magnitudes of two floating point numbers are large enough, then their absolute difference will either be zero or larger than 0.01.  Your convergence test doesn't work for large numbers.  Rather than trying to achieve an certain absolute error, you should instead try to achieve a certain *relative* error, i.e., relative to the magnitude of the number you're dealing with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First observation is that your logic will get you a square root, not a cubic root.

The second thing is that your random numbers can contain negative values which will never converge for a square root.

If you really wanted a cubic root, you could do it like this:

```
def cubic(number):
    result = number
    while abs(number/result/result - result) > 0.01:
        result += (number/result/result - result)/2
    return result
```

you could also approach this in a generic fashion by creating a newton/raphson general purpose function that takes a delta function as parameter to use on a number parameter:

```
def newtonRaphson(delta,n):
    result = n
    while abs(delta(n,result)) > 0.01:
        result += delta(n,result)/2
    return result

def cubic(n,r): return n/r/r - r
def sqrt(n,r):  return n/r - r
```

The use the newtonRaphson method with your chosen delta function:

```
newtonRaphson(sqrt,25)   # 5.000023178253949

newtonRaphson(cubic,125) # 5.003284700817307
```

Comment: "The second thing is that your random numbers can contain negative values which will never converge for a square root."

Values could not be negative. Used formula and values of base ( m * 10) and index (**c) wont allow that, "a" can take values on from range <0;1^100>. And i made mistake in question. Function is suposed to square root

Comment: You are right, I missed the double asterisks, my bad.  So c is used as a power and 10**c may produce a fraction but not a negative number.  What about m == 0, that would produce a value of 0 for a and as far as I can tell, would result in a division by zero or an infinite loop if you get past that.  Floating point precision is roughly 16 decimal digits so it will produce infinite loops for extreme values such as 1e-30.